# Which class has access to the best 'stay at home' adventuring methods?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

Assuming a 20th level character, which class would allow them to remotely assist a party of adventurers without ever leaving a well-warded personal sanctum?  In 3.5e/PF, there existed a plethora of spells mostly based around the Wizard to support this kind of 'off-site meddling' but I know less about 5E and what Wizards and their ilk can accomplish there (especially at higher levels).

For the purposes of this question, assume the following;

- The character is completely unwilling to leave their sanctum unless they have some inherent way to cheat death that is 100% reliable (paying a powerful cleric to resurrect you after X time doesn't count for our paranoid and suspicious protagonist).
- Class features that are mobile (such as Familiars or Animal Companions) can leave the sanctum, as can summoned or bound creatures.
- They have intentionally chosen their class and even found some way of acquiring reasonable magic items towards this goal - they are a purpose-built 'remote assistance' character.

'Best' is not simply damage-per-round but overall quality of assistance - a battery of divinations doesn't directly do damage but does allow the party to bypass encounters, effectively doing all the damage of the enemy hp of that encounter.  Remote healing is not damage but can keep party members alive to do more damage, so on.  In this case I am not looking at any specific character level for the party being assisted, but rather at spells, techniques, or class features that would apply to the widest range of parties successfully.  Consider this less 'bob stays at home and still helps the party' but more 'Mordenkainen's Magical Assist (MMA) Incorporated'.

Comment: I'm not sure there are enough different applicable features/spells/etc. that answers won't be able to decide a best, but the true test of that is to see what answers roll in. (I'm not stopping close voters, but offering a perspective)

Comment: Out of curiosity, you're getting answers that are more of a workaround to get the caster to be with the party. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What are you trying to use this for?

Answer (score 10):

### Any character with *simulacrum*, or better yet, *wish*.

At 20th level, you are a paragon among mortal creatures, being able to contend with fierce monsters on your own, and some of the most powerful enemies when in a group.

As such, a simulacrum (which is just a slightly weaker version of yourself) is the ideal companion to send with your party if your are sanctum-bound:

> You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid that is within range for the entire Casting time of the spell... the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates.

This simulacrum lets you loan most of the abilities that you would contribute if you were physically present with two exceptions:

> it has half the creature's hit point

...and...

> The simulacrum lacks the ability to learn or become more powerful, so it never increases its level or other abilities, nor can it regain expended spell slots.

Its inability to use spell slots is the most crippling, but you can get around this by using *wish* to create a new simulacrum each day:

> The basic use of [*wish*] is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower.

...and then having the simulacrum cast *teleport* to return to your party. This will dismiss the former, now spent *simulacrum* and provide your party with a brand new illusion of yourself with fresh spell slots (minus a 9th-level and 7th level one).

You will also need to have your simulacrum cast *plane shift* and then *teleport* if the party is on another plane of existence. This would cost the simulacrum's 8th level slot as well. You could avoid expending the simulacrum's 7th and 8th level slot if the character is willing to ferry the simulacrum to the party which would take less than a minute outside of the sanctum.

### Which classes?

So which classes get access to these spells?

*Simulacrum* is a wizard spell, so you would need to be a wizard or a bard who can gain it through the Magical Secrets class feature:

> By 10th level, you have plundered magical knowledge from a wide spectrum of disciplines. Choose two spells from any classes, including this one. A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip.
>
> [...]
>
> You learn two additional spells from any classes at 14th level and again at 18th level.

*Wish* and *teleport* are available to sorcerers and wizards (and bards once again using Magical Secrets for *wish*). A cleric of the Arcane Domain could also gain one or both of these spells through the Arcane Mastery class feature:

> At 17th level, you choose four spells from the wizard spell list, one from each of the following levels: 6th, 7th, 8th, and 9th. You add them to your list of domain spells. Like your other domain spells, they are always prepared and count as cleric spells for you.

In summary, these classes:

- Bard
- Cleric (Arcana Domain)
- Sorcerer
- Wizard

*note: Sorcerer doesn't get easy access to* plane shift *if that is necessary, and have no summoning spells which is mentioned later in this answer*

*note 2: Wizards have the most diverse access to summoning spells, so are likely the best choice, but clerics and bards still get enough to where they are not completely outshined*

### Magic Items

First, you want enough magic items to gear up your *simulacrum*. Preferably including a handful of **staves or similar items that can regain charges** if you aren't using the *wish* and *teleport* option for when the simulacrum runs out of spell slots. If you are worried about the half-health, you could also send the simulacrum with an ***amulet of health*** to bolster its survivability.

Secondly, if on the same plane of existence, you can also help from your sanctum by using a ***crystal ball*** which affords unlimited scrying:

> The typical crystal ball, a very rare item, is about 6 inches in diameter. While touching it, you can cast the scrying spell (save DC 17) with it.

Not only would this let a wished simulacrum see the location they are teleporting to (to avoid a mishap), you can also provide key intel to your party (either through *sending* for either class option except sorcerer, or by using a special variant of the *crystal ball*, see below).

If you have access to legendary magic items, each *crystal ball* variant could be extremely useful. One would let you attempt to read the minds of enemies you are scrying on, one would let you communicate with the party telepathically, and the other would provide truesight for your sensor.

Next, if you are using *wish* for fresh simulacra each day, get yourself a ***helm of teleportation***. This way you can save your simulacrum from having to use their 7th level spell slot to get to the party. Make sure to tell the expended simulacrum to bring the helm back at the end of the day. Some days you won't be able to do this, as you have to wait for the helm to regain slots (since it only regains 1d3 per dawn), but the extra power behind that 7th level slot is nothing to scoff at.

### Other summons

Unfortunately, no summons other than found familiars and created homunculi (for wizards) and steeds (for bards with Magical Secrets) last more than an hour. To send more powerful summons, you will need to cast *planar binding* to extend the duration of the summoning spells. With this, the only real limitation is the cost since each casting of *planar binding* costs 1000 gp. Your best summons with this technique are:

- *conjure celestial* for clerics to summon a couatl
- *conjure elemental* for wizards to summon any of [these elementals](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=7&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=9&filter-cr-max=12&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=)
- *infernal calling* for wizards to summon any of [these devils](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=9&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=10&filter-cr-max=13&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=&filter-tags=58)
- *summon greater demon* for wizards to summon any of [these demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=9&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=9&filter-cr-max=13&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-is-mythic=&filter-has-lair=&filter-tags=59)

Bards can learn any one of these spells, or *conjure fey*, through Magical Secrets (assuming they used their other options for *wish*, *teleport*, and *plane shift*), but sorcerers don't get access to any of them.

It is worth noting that any demon summoned will not be dismissed immediately after 24 hours but instead turn hostile for a few rounds. However, your party should be able to deal with them as they aren't particularly high CR.

**It is highly beneficial to cast *planar binding* at 9th level.** Not only does this let you exert control over more summons, it saves money on any individual summon (since each planar binding costs 1000 gp). With time to prepare you could get your ideal set of summons bound for a year. Just send them with your simulacrum and the party gets a large power bump.

If you are using the *wish* and *teleport* strategy, your simulacrum could even bring 8 chosen summons per day.

Another good, yet costly, idea is to create new summons each day that are customized to the specific challenges that the party is facing. You could add to your team of summons using 7th or 8th level spell slots (since *wish* is taking up your 9th level slot) at the cost of 1000 gp per summon.

Comment: clever workaround! Didn't think about skirting the whole issue of not being present as a possible answer.

Comment: I might add, there's the spell _create homunculus_ on the wizard list that lasts more than an hour, like a familiar.

Comment: @KogarashiKaito added.

Comment: Is there anything you can't do with a Simulacrum? Side note: you could also get to 17 as a Wizard, then dip 3 levels into Warlock for Pact of the Chain and have an Imp familiar as your "scrying sensor", and also pick up things like *Beast Speech* or *Eyes of the Rune Keeper* for improved utility.

Answer (score 3):

### Wizards and Clone

This is a great chance to use the wizard exclusive *clone* spell.

First cast the [Clone spell](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Clone#content) as many times as they can. they will have to wait 120 days from the first casting but once that is done they last forever. This creates a supply of perfect back ups. If the wizard dies their soul just returns to the next clone in line. *Clone* is instantaneous so a wizard can have dozens of clones in process at the same time and it cannot be dispelled.

The wizard's soul can return to the clone even if on another plane of existence, so the wizard can use them even if living on a demiplane, and what 20th level wizard is not. The big thing is not to carry any vital irreplaceable equipment with them as that does not return. This does mean they should be carrying a copy of their spellbook and leave the original at home.

The wizard is now free to help the party, even travel with the party using their full range of skills and spells without risk of death.

The only question is how the wizard gets back after *clone* has activated or when the job is done and this depends on where the wizard lives.

If they live on a demi-plane they can use *[plane shift](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Plane%20Shift#content)* or *[gate](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gate#content)* or even the *[demiplane](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Demiplane#content)* spell for return trips.

If they live on the same plane then they just need to use either *[teleport](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Teleport#content)* or *[teleportation circle](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Teleportation%20Circle#content)*.

**As an up side since they do not need to cast these every day they can actually have high level spells available.**
If they are warry about returning they can always scry on the party or location first.

The only vulnerability they would have is the XGE spell *[soul cage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/soul-cage)* and it is more of a temporary inconvenience (no longer than 8 hours) than actual threat, unless cast by a Lich.

Also don't be evil, Night Hags can trap the souls from evil humanoids they kill and they can do it before the soul reaches the clone.

Comment: You might want to mention the risks of being killed by something which takes your soul.

Comment: @Nick such as? mechanically there is no creature I know of that can take an unwilling soul in the same round they kill something except night hags, which are limited to evil humanoids. So I guess don't be evil.

Comment: @John Any caster with *Soul cage*. For the interaction with *clone*: [Would the Soul Cage spell prevent a soul from transferring to a Clone?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144213/52137)

Comment: @nick devourers have abilities called soul rend and imprison soul but don't do anything to souls, Barghest take a full minute to claim a soul after death, (the clone would activate before that), Liches are described as needing to consume souls but are not given any ability to do so.

Comment: @Someone_Evil, never noticed that spell, good catch. not however that it does not trap a soul permanently.

Comment: @david but it takes a minute to do so, so you would be revived as a clone before they could. In fact Clone could be a good way to protect someone from the Barghest ability.